# How to make entire area of radioButton within a radioGroup clickable?

Tags: android, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I could click on the radioButton in the radioGroup, "upto" the text area displayed after the radioButton but not in the empty space after the text area. Is there a way to make it clickable as well?

I think I have explained the problem clearly, if not please do let me know.˙

Following are the details.

styles.xml

```
<style name="RBStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
    <item name="android:drawable">@drawable/button_background</item>

    <item name="android:paddingLeft">4dp</item>
</style>
```

rb_layout.xml

```
<RadioButton style="@style/RBStyle" />
```

Sample code

```
RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) layoutInflater.inflate(
            buttonResource, null);

radioButton.setText(buttonName);
radioButton.setId(buttonId);
```

Comment: Do you want to make radioGroup click able??

Comment: I tried it and its not working android:clickable="true"

Comment: you can make clickable to parent of your radioGroup view.

Comment: @Vid - This is what I tried

  <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </RadioGroup>

still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting answer for brevity.
Adding LinearLayout params and adding it to radioGroup.addView(...) fixed it.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
radioGroup.addView(radioButton, layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set the RadioGroup's onclicklistener to call radiobutton.toggle.

Comment: I don't get your answer, how is that related to the issue am facing? Can you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

You could expand the RadioButton width to `match_parent`:

```
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Then it will take up as much width as your `RadioGroup` and not stop at just the text length.